# node.js include class file

Tags: javascript, node.js, include

I got 2 files:

start.js

```
    var ConversationModule = require('./src/classes/conversation/Conversation.js');
    ConversationModule.sayhello();
```

conversation.js

```
    var ConversationModule = new Object();

    ConversationModule.sayhello = function () {
    console.log("hello");
    };

    exports.ConversationModule = ConversationModule();
```

In start.js I cannot call the sayhello() method. I get following error

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

I just don't get it why it doesn't work - I'm new to node :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to export `ConversationModule` as a function, which it is not. Use this instead:

```
exports.ConversationModule = ConversationModule;
```

Since you're also assigning the variable as a property of `exports`, you'd have to call it like this:

```
var ConversationModule = require('./file').ConversationModule;
ConversationModule.sayhello();
```

If you don't want to do that, assign the object to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports = ConversationModule;
```

And call it like this:

```
var ConversationModule = require('./file');
ConversationModule.sayhello();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've named the file conversation.js, you probably intend to define solely the "conversation module" in that particular file. (One file per logical module is a good practice) 
In that case, it would be cleaner to change your export code, and leave your require code as you had it originally.

start.js

```
var ConversationModule = require('./src/classes/conversation/Conversation.js');
    ConversationModule.sayhello();
```

conversation.js

```
   var ConversationModule = new Object();

   ConversationModule.sayhello = function () {
     console.log("hello");
   };

   module.exports = ConversationModule;
```

Assigning something to `module.exports` makes this value available when you require the module with `require`.

Answer (score 0):

conversation.js:

```
var conversationModule = new Object();

conversationModule.sayhello = function () {
console.log("hello");
};

exports.conversationModule = conversationModule;
```

start.js:

```
var conversationModule =  require('./src/classes/conversation/Conversation.js').conversationModule;
conversationModule.sayhello();
```